# Transclude angular material md-select breaks options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, directive

I'm making a directive  that transcludes content an unknown number of times, depending on times the user adds it.

```
<loop>
    <md-content layout="column" layout-padding>
      <h2>Row</h2>
        <md-input-container flex class="md-block">
          <label>Input</label>
          <input ng-model="item.input">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="md-block">
          <label>Select</label>
            <md-select ng-model="item.select">
                <md-option ng-repeat="option in options">{{option}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </md-content>
</loop>
```

I want everything inside the loop directive to be appended inside a ng-repeat. The template of my directive contains a placeholder so I can replace the content before compiling inside a custom transclude function

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <placeholder></placeholder>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add item</button>
```

I'm using a custom transclude function, no ngTransclude directive, because I don't want an isolated scope inside the transcluded content so I can update my model.

```
$templateRequest('template.html').then(function(html) {
                        var template = angular.element(html);

                        transclude(scope, function(row) {
                            template.find('placeholder').replaceWith(row);

                            $compile(template)(scope, function(clonedTemplate){
                                element.append(clonedTemplate);
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

So first I transclude and replace the placeholder in my template with the transcluded clone, then I compile my template. When I compile the md-select breaks. I think because it is already compiled after the transclude. I can't replace the placeholder after the compile because then the ng-repeat is already compiled and no placeholders are found.

[See this plnkr for an example](https://plnkr.co/edit/cEODyO5NwbYIFmKXUclc?p=preview). I've simplified the code as much as I could.

Is there an other way of achieving this result or is there something I can change so the md-select doesn't break. The example is with a md-select but also had other custom directives that didn't work. I think it's the same reason.